# Android Studio: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, certificate, virtualbox

I have been getting the following error when I try to load urls from instagram:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

I open the web browser(Chrome) in android studio emulator I get the google chrome error:

> your connection is not private attackers might be trying to steal...
>   NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

But the strange thing is when I open amazon and some sites they work fire but google,facebook,instagram show that error. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more digging around and my antivirus (Bullguard) is the one issuing the SSL certificates for the sites not working (google,facebook,bing,youtube and a few more).

So long story short my Antivirus (Bullguard) has a safe browsing option - turning this off solved the problem. Now the websites work and the SSL certificates are being issues by the appropriate issuer eg. google internet authority g3